# Getting started with opengl

Tags: opengl

There's a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239917/getting-started-with-opengl) to this question on SO.  The link to the [help guide](http://fly.srk.fer.hr/~unreal/theredbook/about.html) references downloadable source code under "How to obtain the sample code".  It references the ftp location

**sgigate.sgi.com**

But FileZilla gives me error "Could not connect to server" and the URL does not respond to ping.

Does anyone know where I can download this code or if the site is coming back up?  I do not see any contact information on the site.

Comment: Example code found on sgi.com is terribly outdated. I strongly discourage learning from that one. Better look at the tutorials at http://lighthouse3d.com as they have a far better quality.

Comment: You could also have a look at the books I suggested here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926357/c-opengl-books/5935977#5935977, as well as the tutorials others suggested in the comments.

Comment: @datenwolf - thanks for the tip.  I'm new to openGL so I would love to avoid confusing or outdated API's.  I don't mind spending money if its the best way to learn.  I am looking at buying the OpenGL SuperBible published 2007 on amazon.com, but the "homemade framework" used in SuperBible in @Bethor 's link is making me think twice.  Maybe that's the best out there though.

Comment: After further research the "homemade framework" is only a problem with the 5th edition of SuperBible.  You can buy the 4th edition instead and use the "OpenGL ES 2.0 programming guide" as a reference for newer stuff.  See  
Zenja Solaja's review http://www.amazon.com/review/R3SGMJ1023A4IN/ref=cm_cr_pr_viewpnt#R3SGMJ1023A4IN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect [these](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/code/samples/redbook/) are probably what you're looking for.